# Mutable objects in Java

Tags: java, mutable

I have three questions:

1) Which objects in Java are mutable (apart from Date)?

2) Some Java versions of Date setters are deprecated although the class is still mutable.  What is the point of this?  I mean they won't remove setters because clients are already using them, so why deprecate them?

3) If the setters on Date are deprecated, how do you add one day to a Date?  Is it possible to do in a non-deprecated way?  Do I have to use Calendar like so?

```
Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
        instance.set(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

1) I suppose you mean famous classes that are mutable but better shouldn't: E.g. `SimpleDateFormat` and other formatters, as they are often used as static fields, possibly by multiple threads. This is an error even if the formatter is not modified explicitely, as it holds internal state that is modified when parse or format is called!

2) These methods are deprecated to make people aware that it is evil to use them, and to enable tools like compilers to detect unwanted usage of them. If you don't call any of these 'evil' methods, `Date` is effectively immutable, so it is thread safe (if published correctly).

3) Since Java 8, you can do this easily by using `java.time.LocalDate`:

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate tomorrow = now.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

Prior to Java 8 it was simple too using `Calendar`:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar tomorrow = (Calendar)now.clone();
tomorrow.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) `ArrayList`: add, remove, ...

2) To encourage developers to use libraries with a better logic

3) Your best option is probably to use libraries such as Joda: `new DateTime().plusDays(1);`

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8, the `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` classes should not be used any more. Use [new java.time classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) instead.